# Schedule crontab job for last sunday in the month

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, backup

We want to extend our backup system to include a monthly end backup. It will be performed the last Sunday in the month but code below is so that I can see it works today on a smaller scale.

Started with (which works)

```
0 12 * * 0 sudo tar -cpzf /media/BackupDisk/wwwJUNEbackup.tar.gz /var/www
```

Have trawled the internet and come up with this code, tested in script file

```
 if [ $(date +%d -d '+7 days') -le '8' ] ; then
    echo "Yes"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```

(For reference this says - if today's date + 7 days is less then or equal to 8 then YES else NO)

But when I try to include into the Sudo's crontrab

```
26 17 * 6 5 [ $(date +%d -d '+7 days') -lt '8' ] && sudo tar -cpzf /media/BackupDisk/wwwJUNEbackup.tar.gz /var/www
```

I get a nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [Cron allowed special character “L” for “Last day of the month” on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89188/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), [run script every last thursday of the month](https://askubuntu.com/q/214831) on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), etc.

Comment: @jww **Comment-1:** As you pointed out in your second comment the question MAY be answered by programming **Comment-2**: As I understand in this specific case "advanced shell syntax" failed to work **in crontab entry** - my answer shows how to make it work anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create trivial script `last_weekday_in_month.sh` and use it in your crontab entry.
You use syntax far beyond basic shell => IMHO it is better to move it to trivial script with specific shell enforced via `#!/...`

```
 12 * * 0 /path/last_weekday_in.month.sh && sudo tar -cpzf /media/BackupDisk/wwwJUNEbackup.tar.gz /var/www
```

last_weekday_in.month.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(date +%d -d '+7 days') -lt '8' ] ; then
  exit 0    
else
  exit 1
fi
```